# How to add layers to MXD programmatically on linux or windows without ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-engine, mxd, linux

Is it possible for me to programmatically create in linux centos 6.4 or a windows with only arcGIS Engine runtime (single use license without sdk)?

Comment: Did you try [IMapDocument.Save in the java sdk](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/java_ao_adf/api/arcobjects/com/esri/arcgis/carto/IMapDocument.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not having the SDK is a major wrench in the gears here. If you have an MXD already on disk, you could use [arcpy.mapping.AddLayer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s300000025000000) in a Python script on a MapDocument object and use [MapDocument.saveACopy](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/MapDocument/00s30000000n000000/) to save out. You can run ArcGIS' Python from an Engine install.

Comment: Thanks, turns our i had two python installs (one from arcgis 10.1 and one from arcgis 10.0) and my IDE was using the wrong install for my runtime license, ands thats why arcpy import was failing